# Angular 4 and WordPress Routing

Tags: wordpress, angular, routes

I have an Angular 4 app running in a wordpress theme. The problem is the routing, my page resolves:

http://myhost.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/main

instead of:

http://myhost.com/main

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, not sure if your problem is the url path or the fact that the app doesn't load while the javascript will be in the theme folder.

I found this [article](https://doppiaeast.com/post/routing-to-individual-articles/) useful that describe how to use the --deploy-url to have the right javascript loaded in the form.

But if the problem is like this other case, i don't know if the correct solution is to change the htaccess file to do the redirections.

Comment: And how is this answering the question? You have to be more explicit (From review)

Comment: Try to build the ng command to build the angular app with the following parameter: --deploy-url wp-content/themes/mytheme/ this will let the router know that the folder where all the angular app component resides are in the theme folder.

Comment: Thak you so much! buiding: ng build --base-href=http://lahr.mx/  --deploy-url=/wp-content/themes/lahr/  --prod result: http://lahr.mx/